# USB Hotplugging callbacks with python on Windows

Tags: python, windows, callback, usb, hotplugging

Is it possible to write a python script such that a function is called whenever a USB device is added or removed on Windows?

[`libusb`](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/) (and corresponding python modules such as [`libusb1`](https://github.com/vpelletier/python-libusb1)) appears to be the most popular solution, but it lacks hotplugging callback registration support  in Windows. A [feature request](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/issues/86) has been open for this since 2015, and it's still not implemented.

I've seen some hacks query Windows' usb devices at some interval, do a diff of the current list of devices from the previous list of devices, and use this as an alternative. Due to the nature of my application, this hack would be a huge security risk and is not a valid solution. I need *actual* callback registration on usb hotplug events.

Though less ideal, I'm open to [writing something in C or C++](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DeviceEnumerationAndPairing) and then writing a python binding to that code, if necessary.

Is it possible to have a python function called when a usb device is connected or disconnected on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use ctypes in python to register a callback for `WM_DEVICECHANGE` messages.

I was successfully able to add register callback functions to usb hotplug events in both linux (using the `libusb1` python module) and windows (using the `ctypes` python module). The bulk of the relevant windows code can be found here:

- https://github.com/BusKill/buskill-app/blob/6c84587b25f7ef3b5300d8c0eda354b11051215e/src/buskill.py#L212-L275

Which is largely based on the code found at these links:

- http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/detect-device-insertion.html
- [Detect media insertion on Windows in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38689090/detect-media-insertion-on-windows-in-python)

```
import win32api, win32con, win32gui
from ctypes import *

#
# Device change events (WM_DEVICECHANGE wParam)
#
DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL = 0x8000
DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE = 0x8001
DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVEFAILED = 0x8002
DBT_DEVICEMOVEPENDING = 0x8003
DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE = 0x8004
DBT_DEVICETYPESSPECIFIC = 0x8005
DBT_CONFIGCHANGED = 0x0018

#
# type of device in DEV_BROADCAST_HDR
#
DBT_DEVTYP_OEM = 0x00000000
DBT_DEVTYP_DEVNODE = 0x00000001
DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME = 0x00000002
DBT_DEVTYPE_PORT = 0x00000003
DBT_DEVTYPE_NET = 0x00000004

#
# media types in DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME
#
DBTF_MEDIA = 0x0001
DBTF_NET = 0x0002

WORD = c_ushort
DWORD = c_ulong


class DEV_BROADCAST_HDR(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("dbch_size", DWORD),
        ("dbch_devicetype", DWORD),
        ("dbch_reserved", DWORD)
    ]


class DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("dbcv_size", DWORD),
        ("dbcv_devicetype", DWORD),
        ("dbcv_reserved", DWORD),
        ("dbcv_unitmask", DWORD),
        ("dbcv_flags", WORD)
    ]


def drive_from_mask(mask):
    n_drive = 0
    while 1:
        if (mask & (2 ** n_drive)):
            return n_drive
        else:
            n_drive += 1


class Notification:
    def __init__(self):
        message_map = {
            win32con.WM_DEVICECHANGE: self.onDeviceChange
        }

        wc = win32gui.WNDCLASS()
        hinst = wc.hInstance = win32api.GetModuleHandle(None)
        wc.lpszClassName = "DeviceChangeDemo"
        wc.style = win32con.CS_VREDRAW | win32con.CS_HREDRAW
        wc.hCursor = win32gui.LoadCursor(0, win32con.IDC_ARROW)
        wc.hbrBackground = win32con.COLOR_WINDOW
        wc.lpfnWndProc = message_map
        classAtom = win32gui.RegisterClass(wc)
        style = win32con.WS_OVERLAPPED | win32con.WS_SYSMENU
        self.hwnd = win32gui.CreateWindow(
            classAtom,
            "Device Change Demo",
            style,
            0, 0,
            win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT,
            0, 0,
            hinst, None
        )

    def onDeviceChange(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        #
        # WM_DEVICECHANGE:
        #  wParam - type of change: arrival, removal etc.
        #  lParam - what's changed?
        #    if it's a volume then...
        #  lParam - what's changed more exactly
        #
        dev_broadcast_hdr = DEV_BROADCAST_HDR.from_address(lparam)

        if wparam == DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
            print("Something's arrived")

            if dev_broadcast_hdr.dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_VOLUME:
                print("It's a volume!")

                dev_broadcast_volume = DEV_BROADCAST_VOLUME.from_address(lparam)
                if dev_broadcast_volume.dbcv_flags & DBTF_MEDIA:
                    print("with some media")
                    drive_letter = drive_from_mask(dev_broadcast_volume.dbcv_unitmask)
                    print("in drive", chr(ord("A") + drive_letter))

        return 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = Notification()
    win32gui.PumpMessages()
```